# Rescue block in Ansible Playbook does not execute

Tags: ansible-2.x

Can someone please enlighten me as to why the below rescue block is not executing when the 2nd task 'Verifying PATCHBUNDLE' fails?

```
 ---

- name: HDP Validation
  hosts: HDP
  serial: 1000
  gather_facts: false
  ignore_errors: true

  tasks:
  -name: PATCHBUNDLE Check
    block:
    - name: Current PATCHBUNDLE
      shell: cat /iv/piv/a00/playbooks/PATCHING/current_patchbundle
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
      register: current_bundle
      run_once: true

     - name: Verifying PATCHBUNDLE - current bundle is set to {{ current_bundle.stdout }}
       shell: "cat /etc/.jumpver | tail -2 | grep USEPATCHBUNDLE={{ current_bundle.stdout }}"
       tags: patch
       register: bundle
  
     rescue: 
     - name: Grab PATCHBUNDLE and PATCHBUNDLE DATE
       shell: "cat /etc/.jumpver | tail -2 | tr '\n' ' ' |  sed 's/USEPATCHBUNDLE=/BUNDLE: /; s/USEPATCHBUNDLEAPPLIEDDATE=/APPLIED: /; s/ $//;'"
       tags: patchdate
       register: bundledate
        
     - debug:
         msg: "{{ bundledate.stdout }}"

     always:
     - name: rpm Kernel Check non-VMs
       shell: rpm -qa --last | grep -.........
```

provides the following output:

```
    PLAY [HDP Validation] ********************************
    
    TASK [Current PATCHBUNDLE] *************
    
    changed: [eagnmnmep3268 -> 127.0.0.1]
    
    TASK [Verifying PATCHBUNDLE - current bundle is set to 2023-04-R32] ********************************
    
    fatal: [eagnmnmep3268]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "cat /etc/.jumpver | tail -2 | grep USEPATCHBUNDLE=2023-04-R32", "delta": "0:00:00.013547", "end": "2023-04-21 18:05:39.012868", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2023-04-21 18:05:38.999321", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
    
    ...ignoring
    
    SKIPS THE RESCUE BLOCK HERE
    
    TASK [rpm Kernel Check non-VMs] ********************************
    
    changed: [eagnmnmep3268]

...... a bunch of other tasks run .....
   
    PLAY RECAP ***************************
    
    eagnmnmep3268   : ok=10   changed=10   unreachable=0    failed=0
```

I'm a novice ansible user. I've poured over the documentation and cannot figure why everything BUT the rescue block executes when 'Verifying PATCHBUNDLE' fails...

Ansible version 2.7.5

SOLVED - turn off ignore errors at the top of the playbooks and add ignore_erros: true to the tasks in the always block should you want the playbook to continue running after encountering an error in this section

```
     ---

- name: HDP Validation
  hosts: HDP
  serial: 1000
  gather_facts: false
  #ignore_errors: true

  tasks:
  -name: PATCHBUNDLE Check
    block:
    - name: Current PATCHBUNDLE
      shell: cat /iv/piv/a00/playbooks/PATCHING/current_patchbundle
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
      register: current_bundle
      run_once: true

     - name: Verifying PATCHBUNDLE - current bundle is set to {{ current_bundle.stdout }}
       shell: "cat /etc/.jumpver | tail -2 | grep USEPATCHBUNDLE={{ current_bundle.stdout }}"
       tags: patch
       register: bundle
  
     rescue: 
     - name: Grab PATCHBUNDLE and PATCHBUNDLE DATE
       shell: "cat /etc/.jumpver | tail -2 | tr '\n' ' ' |  sed 's/USEPATCHBUNDLE=/BUNDLE: /; s/USEPATCHBUNDLEAPPLIEDDATE=/APPLIED: /; s/ $//;'"
       tags: patchdate
       register: bundledate
        
     - debug:
         msg: "{{ bundledate.stdout }}"

     always:
     - name: rpm Kernel Check non-VMs
       shell: rpm -qa --last | grep -
       ignore_erros: true 
      
     - more tasks here.........
```